# Custom code project, WebBrowser related, can't find the elements of specific id in C#

Tags: c#, html, console, getelementbyid

I've been working on a C# based web-browser related program on a console project. Now, here's a piece of code that is working in **Windows Form Application** but in **Console** application it's showing me *'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'*. So far, by doing debugging, taking all the stuff from **HTMLElementCollection** to a **var** by the elementId, it's showing False, which means there's no such id inside the HTML. Now, this code is not wrong cause the same code is working perfectly inside the Windows Form Application. I hope you understand. A little help on this will be appreciated! Thanks.

The piece of code is provided below:

```
if (browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    //Putting the values inside the boxes
    browser.Document.GetElementById("project_title").SetAttribute("value", projectTitle);
    browser.Document.GetElementById("article_title").SetAttribute("value", title);
    browser.Document.GetElementById("article_content").SetAttribute("value", content);
    browser.Document.GetElementById("article_tags").SetAttribute("value", tags);
    browser.Document.GetElementById("article_url_1").SetAttribute("value", url);
    browser.Document.GetElementById("article_keyword_1").SetAttribute("value", keywords);
    browser.Document.GetElementById("article_url_2").SetAttribute("value", url2);
    browser.Document.GetElementById("article_keyword_2").SetAttribute("value", keywords2);
    browser.Document.GetElementById("article_url_3").SetAttribute("value", url3);
    browser.Document.GetElementById("article_keyword_3").SetAttribute("value", keywords3);

    HtmlElementCollection lastElementCollection = browser.Document.All;
    foreach (HtmlElement webpageelement in lastElementCollection)
    {
        if (webpageelement.GetAttribute("value").Contains("Submit"))
            webpageelement.InvokeMember("click");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Please wait for 5 second(s).");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Post has been submitted successfully!");
}
```

Comment: What variable causes the "Object reference not set"

Comment: It's showing at here `browser.Document.GetElementById("project_title").SetAttribute("value", projectTitle);`
Btw, the projectTitle is not null, it has a value, I checked.

Comment: projectTitle is perhaps not null but GetElementById("project_title") IS null it seems. Did you check that too?

Comment: my question is why it's becoming null? just before that line I did an invoke by innerText but it's working fine, no null. Then why null at here?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about browser object has loaded the right content? check the browser.Document element's innerHtml first. (while debugging may be?)

Comment: All okay. I've performed some `.Navigate()` method previously. `browser.Document.All` has got everything...

Comment: the same code is working perfectly in windows form app. but everything except this is not working inside the console.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

Just put a waiting sequence before the first IF statement of your code snippet; like this:

```
while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{  
  Application.DoEvents();
}

if (browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
...
```

**UPDATE: 
Are you using DocumentCompleted event? Check WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs' url property with the url you requested if they are same. Because documentcompleted fires for all files in your web request (like js and css files).**

Comment: can we see the innerHtml value?

Comment: wow, it's not loading the entire part. it's just half... upto a `</script>` tag

Comment: @SaffanAlvy so as you see the problem changes to "why it's loading half of it.."

Comment: Hey, I figured it out. Just have to reload the page to get all the elements. Now the programming is not giving any error... It even also submits the blog post. But inside my blog, there's no new post. I wonder why's that?